# Objective-c Server Side

Tags: python, objective-c, cocoa, server-side

**A bit of background:**
I have been developing apps for the past 2 years for Mac and iOS. I really like Objective-c and Cocoa/Cocoa-Touch framework. I did java and c++ before I started programing for iOS and now when I look at these languages i literally get a headache (The syntax mainly but also lack of classes provided by Cocoa framework). I think I have become too used to Objective-c [] syntax and the rich Cocoa-Framework (Things like NSDictionary, NSPredicate, NSString....)

**Now:**
I need to do some server side programming. I was wondering what's my best option. I certainly don't want to go with Java, but is there a language that is closely like Objective-C that I can use which has a framework like Cocoa with classes similar to NSString, NSDictionary and such...? or better yet, can I even use Objective-C itself in server side programming?

Edit: I took a look at python, and as far as syntax goes, i like it. But of course, that's just syntax, there's ALOT more to a language than just syntax...

Thanks.

Comment: Alas, in the olden days, WebObjects http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebObjects were a premier product of NeXTSTEP (which took over Apple) and as such it used Objective-C as the language. Later it adopted Java, and now it's almost defunct... iTunes Store still uses it (presumably in its Java incarnation), though.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

What's stopping you from writing server-side applications in Objective-C? Xcode comes with templates for command-line applications (choose 'Foundation' rather than 'C' or 'Core Foundation').

If the requirement of using OS X on the server is too much, you can opt for a Linux/BSD distribution and use [GNUstep](http://www.gnustep.org/). Almost the entirety of Cocoa is reproduced (in delightful open-source form!) in the GNUstep project. It's usually as simple as recompiling on your target platform with zero changes required to the source code.

Comment: And you will end up with a stack that is used by at least 20 people in the world. Nice!

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a nice little bit of "servlet" plumbing for mongoose server:

http://www.crocodella.com.br/2011/06/java-style-servlets-in-obj-c-using-mongoose-server/

Answer (score 0):

I concur, try doing it in objective-c
But if you are looking for a similar language that also has rich wen development frameworks widely used, take a look at Ruby. 
The syntax is quite different but the object model is fairly similar and won't actually feel that far away. The framework Ruby on Rails is also a very rich one with a nice MVC approach and good documentation.

But still, objective-c would be awesome.